# Ruby ActiveStorage automatically deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

def create
    @photo = Photo.new(create_sanitized_params)
    @photo.image.attach(params[:image])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @photo.save!
    format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully uploaded.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @photo }
  else
    format.html { render :new, notice: 'Could not upload photo.' }
    format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Why does it attach and then automatically delete itself?

```
Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-05 15:40:42 -0400
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"W2Ha1upiwrwz1aE2dHWt6eDKRw6SL/0W02Au+d0JoMbDDIjOZe6pJE2eRFCW6w8i9v0eF8twzWq0OguG7VDT9A==", "photo"=>{"title"=>"test foto", "description"=>"foto", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb09924f350 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/xm/9j_21czd0vqg_kdr92sp5z840000gn/T/RackMultipart20190905-4691-2u6fh.png>, @original_filename="Screen Shot 2019-09-02 at 5.34.23 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2019-09-02 at 5.34.23 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "photo_album_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
  Disk Storage (4.8ms) Uploaded file to key: XRjgRY3dCznEB3TRFRydg9Aw (checksum: euj92BVN0O7w99rJUS+rvA==)
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:6
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "XRjgRY3dCznEB3TRFRydg9Aw"], ["filename", "Screen Shot 2019-09-02 at 5.34.23 PM.png"], ["content_type", "image/png"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 731315], ["checksum", "euj92BVN0O7w99rJUS+rvA=="], ["created_at", "2019-09-05 19:40:42.827609"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:6
   (4.9ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:6
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:6
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:6
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists (1.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["blob_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
  ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:7
  Disk Storage (0.2ms) Deleted file from key: XRjgRY3dCznEB3TRFRydg9Aw
  Disk Storage (0.1ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/XRjgRY3dCznEB3TRFRydg9Aw/
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:11
  PhotoAlbum Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "photo_albums".* FROM "photo_albums" WHERE "photo_albums"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:11
  Photo Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("title", "description", "photo_album_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "test foto"], ["description", "foto"], ["photo_album_id", 1], ["created_at", "2019-09-05 19:40:42.873291"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-05 19:40:42.873291"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:11
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:11
No template found for PhotosController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 194ms (ActiveRecord: 76.8ms)
```

Does anyone know why it would insert my file, and then automatically delete itself? I don't know why it would do this.

Comment: Can you show the entire controller and relevant model? It looks like it's checking if the `image` (ActiveStorage) exists, and skipping it because it already exists. Is this a `has_one_attached`? If this is I'm suspecting this is unintended behavior and I think it should be able to be overwritten.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hLCtvqss

This is my photo model and controller.

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to remove @photo.image.attach() because it automatically get attched in Photo.new(create_params) <= it gets the image from here

Comment: What I _think_ is happening is that you're successfully attaching an image object (`params[:photo][:image]` via `create_sanitized_params`) and then afterwards, you're attaching a non-existent image via `params[:image]` which deletes the image. I would put a breakpoint after the `@photo = Photo.new(create_sanitized_params)` and check if `@photo.image.attached?`